# How do I pass the first wave on hard?

Tags: whiteboard-tower-defense

I was able to beat the Normal difficulty reasonably easy with a strategy similar to this:

[image]

Unfortunately, the Hard difficulty is considerably more difficult - in fact, I cannot even pass the first wave!

I looked for a walk-through to give me some pointers, and I found [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pWfqWbmC9tg). This strategy seems to work in the video, but is woefully inadequate during my attempts. I'm not sure, but I think that there may be differences in versions of the game. If it does matter, I am playing the version [here](http://www.kongregate.com/games/funinvegas/whiteboard-tower-defense).

What is a good strategy and layout to beat the first (and hopefully subsequent) waves on the Hard difficulty?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason, I was unable to beat this level after beating the normal variant. But, I reloaded the game and was able to get past the first level. I believe this indicates that there might be a bug that makes the Hard enemies much more difficult after completing the normal mode.

Either way, after reloading I was able to pass the first level with a layout like this (similar to the image in the question):

```
XO                 X = entrance to the maze
XO                 O = Peon Tower
 O
 O
 O
 O
```